# How Do I Use A Class As A Parameter In A Static Method

Tags: java, parameters, reference, static

I'm aware that in static methods you can't use the keyword "this".

Now, I also know that if I want to call a method from that class that I'm currently in, I can use the class name,

Example: Main.someStaticMethod();

Now, if I want to use that class (the same as in the example above) in a parameter, how would I do that?

```
Main.someStaticMethodWithParam(Main);
```

That Doesn't work since the IDE thinks main is a parameter and thus just comes up with the error: Undefined variable.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Use `Class<?>` as parameter definition and you can call it with `Main.class`.

Comment: Umm.. why do you even ask that. I want to do that because I'd like to know exactly how it works. I'm a beginner :).

Comment: Jeroen I'll try that :)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an instance of the class to your static method:

```
public class Main {
    private int x;
    public static <T> void printClassName(Class<T> clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    }
    public static void main() {
        printClassName(Main.class);
    }
}
```

Prints (assuming the class is not inside a package):

```
Main
```